# Remote SQL Server configuration : which ports?

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a VPS running Windows Server 2012 in a public IP. I've installed SQL Server on it and changed the firewall allowing all incoming / outcoming TCP connections on port 1433.

However when i try to connect on this server remotely from a PHP application, i get the error below :

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist
```

Is there any other ports / protocols i should allow to the connection work ?

When i try to telnet the server on the port 1433 :

> Connecting To xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx...Could not open connection to the host,
>   on port 1433: Connect failed

Comment: You might need more, depending on if your using a named instance, etc. The documentation covers the [Ports used by SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/configure-the-windows-firewall-to-allow-sql-server-access?view=sql-server-2017#ports-used-by-) very well.

Comment: @Larnu My server is configured as default instance, but even so, only allowing port 1433 is not enough...

Comment: Have you verified that you can connect to port 1433 from the PHP server? (E.g., `telnet <server> 1443`?)

Comment: If your attempting to connect via a public IP then the internet facing router would need to be configured to open/forward the relevant ports to the internal address.

Comment: @AlexHowansky When trying to telnet i get his : Connecting To xxx.xxx.xxx.xx...Could not open connection to the host, on port 1433: Connect failed

Comment: <voice of Adam Savage> Well there's your problem...

Comment: Sounds like @AlexK. was on the right track, your firewall is blocking to port/isn't routing it.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Yes, i know the firewall is blocking it, but i already created rules for TCP in / out on port 1433... is there any port to change ?

Comment: guys I've got a sql server running on a remote server, but I've got a problem to access the remote server I access with ip xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3333, it already has a port in the ip, how can I access to the 1433 port of sql server?

Answer (score 0):

This solved my issue !

```
Enable remote connections for SQL Server:
a) In SQL Server Configuration Manager, expand SQL Server Network Configuration, and then click Protocols for <instancename>.
b) In the details pane, right-click one of the available protocols, and then click Properties.
c) To enable the TCP/IP protocol (or named pipes) for remote connections, set the Enabled box to Yes.
```

Comment: Ah ok, sounds like the firewall was allowing 1433 but the server daemon itself wasn't listening on that port yet. Note, if you haven't already, you'll want to lock your firewall rule down to just the IP of your PHP server. You don't want your SQL server wide open to the Internet.